# Align Columns to the right of the "table" in ListCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, listctrl

My current setup is like this:
[image]

With the columns in the ListCtrl being created as so:

```
self.list = wx.ListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER | wx.LC_HRULES | wx.LC_VRULES)
self.list.Show(True)


col_rank = self.list.InsertColumn(0, "Rank")
col_name = self.list.InsertColumn(1, "Team Name")
col_country = self.list.InsertColumn(2, "Country")
col_pinned = self.list.InsertColumn(3, "Pinned")
```

However I want the Country and Pinned Columns to be aligned to the right of the window, not to the left as they currently are. I attempted to do this by setting the width of Team Name very wide but this make the application unable to be resized without breaking the view. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right alignment of columns. You can set column widths (possibly dynamically, i.e. update the width of the right most column to take up all the remaining space in `wxEVT_SIZE` handler) and you can align the text inside the column to the right using `wxLIST_FORMAT_RIGHT` with `AppendColumn()`.